# How to get the Package-List of a debian/ubuntu package?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, package-management, aptitude

It's possible to view the Package-List of a debian/ubuntu package, using the package management tools like apt, aptitude or dpkg?

I need to list the packages provided by a package, the list is visible in the dsc file:

Example:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lxc/lxc_1.0.0~beta3-0ubuntu1.dsc
Section Package-List.

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/dsc . A short answer is that you can not generate a .dsc file from a binary .deb package. A somewhat longer answer is that you can get information out of an installed package with dpkg-query(1) (see accompanied manual page and section for `-f, --showformat` especially).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apt-cache showsrc` and use awk (or similar tools) to get the output you want:

```
$ apt-cache showsrc lxc | awk '/Package-List/{a=1;next}/^[^ ]/{a=0}a{print $1}'
lxc
lxc-dbg
lxc-dev
```